# Is there a utility to take an oracle dump into Google BigQuery?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, cloud, google-bigquery

Hello all :) I'm having problems moving data to Google's BigQuery from an Oracle 10g server.

Is there a program or library that takes an Orale dump and mounts it on BigQuery?

I have searched extensively and have encountered no solution so far. I'm posting here with the BigQuery tag in the hope that someone has done it but didn't document it on the internet.

Best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used it, but would OraDump-to-CSV work for you?

http://www.convert-in.com/ord2csv.htm

Once you have a CSV, you can easily import it in into BigQuery.